# Google directions service zero results. Is it a bug?

Tags: google-maps, directions

I found that sometimes google  directions service returns zero results with transit transort mode. At the same time https://maps.google.com/ can finds rout for the same adresses.

Pls try:

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=Uzhhorod&destination=Zhytomyr&sensor=false&departure_time=1351544080&mode=transit

Returns `ZERO_RESULTS`, however [Google Maps itself returns many results](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Uzhhorod&daddr=Zhytomyr&hl=en&ll=49.31438,25.532227&spn=3.147758,8.453979&sll=49.353095,25.47339&sspn=3.145242,8.453979&geocode=FQDl5QIdCxZUASnZ47ZEuRk5RzE8KgQwAa6mDQ%3BFTrT_gId60u1ASldNforo2QsRzEp4rnZo9JK8Q&dirflg=r&ttype=now&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&mra=ltm&t=m&z=8&start=0).

http://maps.google.com (->directions) 
Origin: Uzhhorod
Destination: Zhytomyr
Departure at: 10/29/12 20:38 (1351544080 - Unix Time stamp)

What is going on?

Comment: That is strange -- I see no technical reason why you'd get no results.  Perhaps Google's licensing agreement with the transit provider prohibits them from making the data available via API?

Comment: I think no because, when i use other time( before and after that) - i can find routes using direction API with the same provider.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is undocumented time window(time limits) for departure date. For example, google direction service can search only routes with in 8 hours after departure_time(we need to clear up this window from google developers team) . So solution will be to add 8 hours to departure_time and try for results, and make loop during suitable time. I tested, that works. I think that is the secret of maps.google.com